# Обращение к классу PDO внутри метода другого класса

Tags: php, ооп, pdo

Кто может подсказать в чем ошибка? 
Хочу обратиться к классу PDO внутри метода моего класса. Возможно ли это? Связь с БД установил, $pdo = new PDO сделал сначала каждой страницы.
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in W:\domains\
Вот собственно сам код:

```
public function register(){
    $this->login=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login']));
    $this->password=md5(mb_strtolower(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password']))));
    $this->email=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
    //Проверка на зарегестрированного пользователя в БД
    $errlog = "SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE login = '$this->login'";
    $errmail= "SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE email = '$this->email'";
    $result1 = $pdo->prepare($errlog);
    $result2 = $pdo->prepare($errmail);
    $result1->execute(); 
    $result2->execute();
    $number_of_rows1 = $result1->fetchColumn(); 
    $number_of_rows2 = $result2->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: в этом методе нет переменной `$pdo` прочитайте про области видимости переменных

Comment: Даже если я вызываю конфиг файл перед каждой страницей с подключением $pdo ? По факту получается так, на странице регистрации :
`$pdo = new PDO ...`
`$newUser = new User;`
`$newUser ->register();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инстанс ПДО надо передавать в конструктор класса и присвоить приватной переменной.

```
class User {
    private $pdo;
    public function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function register(){
        $login=trim($_POST['login']);
        $password=trim($_POST['password']);
        $email=trim($_POST['email']);
        //Проверка на зарегестрированного пользователя в БД
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE login = ? or email = ?";
        $stmt= $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$login, $email]); 
        $user = $stmt->fetch();
        $number_of_rows1 = $user && $user['login'] == $login; 
        $number_of_rows2 = $user && $user['email'] == $email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Во! Спасибо мил человек)

Comment: Только обрати внимание на остальной говнокод, который я исправил.

Comment: Ну так, первый проект же) а чем не понравился мой код? Суть отлова то одна

Comment: последние две строки не в тему остались

Comment: @ДенисЕлисеев в глазах рябит от твоего отлова. И вместо подготовленного запроса у тебя самолет из соломы.